# Facebook Apps: View all scores for your app?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-apps

I had an issue with my game that allowed people to easily fake their score.  How can I, as the administrator, view ALL scores so I can delete the offending ones?  I don't want to delete all scores, which I'm aware is possible.

I've looked all through my app page including the insights and do not see scores anywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I'm aware there is no way to do this without querying each individual user's scores (you can also query a user's friends' scores if you have their access token from /your_app_id/scores).

I've looked for an API for this as well (even to pull the top global scores) and haven't been able to find one.